# VSCode でコーディングしてもプログラムが実行できない

Tags: python, vscode

Python3.8.5をMacで学んでいるものです。IDLEからVSCodeに移行しようと少し触ってみているのですが、問題があります。

IDLEで書いたコードを取り込み、実行すると正常に動きます（実はこれも完璧に正常ではありません。IDLEではcatと入力すれば動いたコードが、”cat＂でなければ動かないようになりました）

しかしVSCode上でコーディングすると、そもそもシンタックスに色がつかない上に、実行を押しても "環境の選択" と出てくるだけで、どれを押しても何も起こりません。
何か間違った手順を踏んでしまっていますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず VSCode と IDLE の違いを理解する必要があると思います。

#### VSCode

VSCode は「エディタ」の一つで、ソースコードを編集するツールです。ソースコードを見やすくハイライトしたりする機能に長けていますが、**エディタ自体にプログラムを実行する機能は備えていません。**

ただし VSCode の場合には、拡張機能をインストールしたり、いくつかの設定を済ませておくことでプログラムの実行を **ある程度簡単に** 呼び出す事ができる仕組みがあります。

詳しくは「VSCode Python 実行」などで検索すれば手順が色々と出てくるはずなので、まずはそれらを参照してみてください。

**例:**
[VSCodeでのPython、Jupyter実行環境の構築方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/SolKul/items/f078877acd23bb1ea5b5)

> - Pytho拡張機能をインストール
> - プログラムを書く
> - Python実行環境を整える
> - プログラムを実行

#### IDLE

IDLE は「統合開発環境(IDE)」の一つで、**エディタの機能に加えて** プログラムの実行やデバッグに必要な機能を備えたツールです。
IDE と言えば色々ありますが、IDLE に関しては Python に付属しているので学習用の取っ掛かりとして使われるのかもしれませんが、他の IDE に比べれると機能は限られています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。私はpython３、VScode、Anacondaだけをインストールしていました。どのブログを読み漁っても、大体この三つだからです。しかしVScodeでファイルというところを押して入力画面にprint("hello")と打っても、まずシンタックスに色がつきませんし、実行しても、環境の選択と出てきて、どれかを適当に押すと、

Comment: {
    "python.pythonPath": "/opt/anaconda3/bin/python",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
}と出てきます。一体何を改善すれば良いのでしょうか

Answer (score 0):

新規ファイルを作成した時に、言語の選択をしていなかったのだと思います。