# VSCode で Python のコードを入力してもシンタックスハイライトされない

Tags: python, vscode

プログラミングをついこの間始めたものです。あるYouTubeの動画を見て、私はmacに、python３.8.5、VScode、Anacondaをインストールしました。そして、VScodeを開いて、ファイルというところを押して、真っ暗な入力画面に`print("hello")`と打ちました。

違和感を覚えたのは、まずシンタックスに色がつかなかったことです。
そしてそれを実行しても、「環境の選択」と出てきて、表示されたものをどれかを適当に押すと、以下のコードが出てくるだけです。

```js
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/opt/anaconda3/bin/python",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
}
```

自分が何を何のためにインストールして、今自分が何をやっているのかわからない状態です。python3.8.5についてきたIDLEというものはシンタックスに色はつくし、書いたコードを実行すれば対話シェルに結果が示されます。他のアプリもこのようなシンプルにコードを書けると思っていたのですが違うようです。

どうか、私が今、何を何のためにインストールして、何をやっているのか、そして何をするべきかご教授願います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[前回の質問への回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/69526) は読んでいただけましたか？

IDLE は Python 向けの IDE なので、特に指定がなくても Python のコードを入力すればハイライトされるのでしょう。

一方、VSCode は Python 以外の言語を記述する際にも使用できるので、新規作成でコードを入力しただけでは、そのコードが何の言語なのか判別できないため、ハイライトされません。

Python のコードとしてハイライトして欲しいなら、いったん `FILE.py` のように `.py` の拡張子を付けて保存するか、コマンドパレットを呼び出して "Change Language Mode" から言語を選択してあげる必要があります。

参考:
[VSCodeで拡張子がついていないファイルでもSyntax Highlighを行う。 | note](https://note.com/teitei_tk/n/n413f22c1a936)

> Command + Shift + p で表示されるコマンドパレットでChange Language Modeで
> 好きな言語のSyntaxを選べます。

Comment: はい、読ませていただきました。ありがとうございます。今回のご回答のお陰で、シンタックスにハイライトがつくようにはなりました。そしてなぜか分かりませんが、anacondaを再インストールしたらコーディングできるようになりました。ありがとうございます。またお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sejuku.net/blog/40607
このサイトを見てみたらいかがでしょうか
「Visual Studio Codeは、あくまで高機能なソースコードエディタのため、Pythonの実行環境は含まれていません。そのため、Visual Studio Codeとは別に、Pythonの実行環境を用意する必要があります。」
上のサイトより引用
Anacondaは、 科学計算（データサイエンス、機械学習アプリケーション、大規模データ処理、予測分析など）のためのPythonおよびR言語の無料のオープンソースディストリビューションであり、パッケージ管理とデプロイメントを簡略化することを狙ったものである。

Anaconda はデータサイエンス向けの環境を提供するプラットフォームです。科学技術計算などを中心とした、多くのモジュールやツールのコンパイル済みバイナリファイルを提供しており、簡単にPythonを利用する環境を構築できます

Comment: なぜか分かりませんが、anacondaを再インストールしたらコーディングできるようになりました。ありがとうございます。またお願いします。